# Angular: How to select a specific Excel worksheet before importing file?

Tags: html, angular, excel, typescript, frontend

I'm implementing a feature that allows the user to select a specific Excel worksheet from a dropdown select list before importing the file, however, I'm unsure how to add the worksheet names to the dropdown list. I've currently placeholder names in the dropdown list as I'm not sure how to incorporate the "sheetNames" function into the current "Worksheet" interface.

Dropdown Select:

```
<mat-form-field id="worksheetStyle"appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Excel Worksheet</mat-label>
                        <mat-select>
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let worksheet of worksheets" [value]="worksheet.value">
                            {{worksheet.viewValue}}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript:

```
  worksheets: Worksheet[] = [
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Sheet_1'},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'Sheet_2'},
    {value: '3', viewValue: 'Sheet_3'},
  ];


  sheetNames(workbook) {                             
    var arr = new Array;

    for (let i = 0; i <= workbook.length; i++) {
      arr.push(workbook.SheetNames[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example for you. You necessarily don't need to process the sample data you have provided. But incase you do want to do that, I refactored that part slightly as well. You were on the right track, some small syntax. If you can get your workbook in such an object as your sample data that would be great. But on a side note, sounds sketchy to know the file name before user even attempts to import it (e.g add file via input), but perhaps that data is coming from somewhere else which is not the topic of the question.

```html
<mat-form-field id="worksheetStyle" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Excel Worksheet</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let worksheet of worksheets" [value]="worksheet.value">
      {{ worksheet.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<br />
You have selected {{ selected }}

<br />
<br />
SheetNames() = {{ arr }}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  selected: any;
  arr = [];

  worksheets: any[] = [
    { value: '1', viewValue: 'Sheet_1' },
    { value: '2', viewValue: 'Sheet_2' },
    { value: '3', viewValue: 'Sheet_3' },
  ];

  /**
   * This is uneccessary (for selecting on template at least)
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sheetNames(this.worksheets)
  }

  sheetNames(workbook: any) {
  
    for (let sheet of workbook) {
      this.arr.push(sheet.viewValue)
    }
    console.log(this.arr)
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-zngwtj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Excellent answer thank you Joosep, I've edited my post to reflect another question I have. If you take away the hardcoded values (Sheet_1 etc.), how do you add the names of the worksheets to an empty array?

Comment: Glad I could help. But please, if you have more questions just start a new one and revert your current question to original state. That way others can also help you and current post is not confusing to future readers.